# How can I use ApolloClient to pass fresh authorization headers to the server when using the Firebase Admin SDK?

Tags: firebase, gatsby, apollo-client, apollo-server

I am using the Firebase Admin SDK for my server — in my case Apollo Server running in google cloud functions. Upon login, the server generates a token and returns it to the client. The client puts it into local storage and uses it for future requests. This works fine until the token expires 1 hour later.

How can I refresh the token so that the user doesn't need to keep logging in every hour?

#### On the server, login returns a token; the client will put it in local storage

```
exports.login = async (email, password) => {
    const data = await firebase
        .auth()
        .signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, password);

    const token = await data.user.getIdToken();
    return token;
}
```

#### On the client, ApolloClient includes the token with auth headers

I'm using Gatsby in this example, but I've had the same trouble doing this with create-react-app.

```
import fetch from 'isomorphic-fetch';
import {ApolloClient, HttpLink, InMemoryCache} from '@apollo/client';
import {setContext} from 'apollo-link-context';

const httpLink = new HttpLink({
  uri: `${process.env.GATSBY_API_URL}`,
  fetch,
});

const authLink = setContext((_, {headers}) => {
  const token = localStorage.getItem('myUserToken');
  return {
    headers: {
      ...headers,
      authorization: token ? `Bearer ${token}` : '',
    },
  };
});

export const client = new ApolloClient({
  cache: new InMemoryCache(),
  link: authLink.concat(httpLink),
  connectToDevTools: true,
});
```

One potential solution might be, if I didn't use Graphql and ApolloClient, to import `firebase.auth` on the client and generate a refreshed auth token before every request. For example:

```
// firebase_service.js
import * as firebase from 'firebase/app';
import 'firebase/auth';
import { config } from './firebase-config';

firebase.initializeApp(config);

export const auth = firebase.auth;

// getData.js
import { auth } from '../firebase_service';
import axios from 'axios';

const getData = () => {
    const token = await auth().currentUser.getIdToken(true);
    return axios
      .get(FIREBASE_API_URL, {
        headers: { authorization: `Bearer ${token}` },
      })
      .then((res) => res.data);
}
```

Would there be a way to do something like this but with ApolloClient, so that the headers include a fresh token when appropriate?